# A black box appear above the posts page in Android

Tags: bug, mobile-web

In mobile view of all sites, a black box is appearing at some parts when viewing list of questions page (but not for any other page like specific post, profile, ask, etc., nor is it happening for full site view) in Chrome as well as Chrome Canary for Android in CyanogenMod 12.0.

[image: screen shot 1]

[image: screen shot 2]

Comment: Not sure SE is going to put any effort to fix an issue in a custom ROM.

Comment: FWIW, I am not seeing this in Chrome on Android 7.1.2.

Comment: ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้‌​้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้‌​้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้‌​้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้‌​้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้‌​้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้‌​้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้‌​้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้‌​้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้‌​้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้‌​้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้‌​้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้‌​้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้‌​้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้‌​้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้‌​้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้‌​้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้‌​้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้‌​้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้‌​้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้‌​้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้‌​้้้้้้้้

Comment: @ale happens only to she sites when in mobile view. No issue on full site view. I didn't checked on any other device. Thanks for the nougat feedback.